# Python regex split a string by one of two delimiters

Tags: python, regex

I wanted to cut up a string of email addresses which may be separated by any combination of commas and white-space.

And I thought it would be pretty straight-forward :

```
sep = re.compile('(\s*,*)+')
print sep.split("""a@b.com, c@d.com

   e@f.com,,g@h.com""")
```

But it isn't. I can't find a regex that won't leave some empty slots like this :

```
['a@b.com', '', 'c@d.com', '', 'e@f.com', '', 'g@h.com']
```

I've tried various combinations, but none seem to work. Is this, in fact, possible, with regex?

Comment: This should not be a community wiki post.

Comment: It really shouldn't be a community wiki post. But still, this problem is nicely solved using regexes. A valid regex usage! +1

Comment: i think because he answered it himself

Answer (score 14):

Doh!

It's just this.

```
sep = re.compile('[\s,]+')
```

Comment: In Perl (probably in Python, due to the fact that it appears to be doing the same thing) using ()s in a regex when splitting causes the split() to preserve the match (between the parens), and return a list with the pattern match in between the items you want. So maybe don't use ()s in a split.

Answer (score 3):

without re

```
line = 'e@d , f@g, 7@g'

addresses = line.split(',')    
addresses = [ address.strip() for address in addresses ]
```

Answer (score 2):

I like the following...

```
>>> sep= re.compile( r',*\s*' )
>>> sep.split("""a@b.com, c@d.com

   e@f.com,,g@h.com""")
['a@b.com', 'c@d.com', 'e@f.com', 'g@h.com']
```

Which also seems to work on your test data.

Comment: +1: I don't know why this was down voted before, but it works quite nicely.

Comment: That regex will match the empty string, since it uses star quantifiers for everything. Really you want to split on at least one character; the OP's solution with a character class and plus quantifier is better, not to mention much clearer to read.

Comment: I see.  I don't think regular expressions can be ranked on readability, but I get your point about matching at least one character.