# Python: split files using multiple split delimiters

Tags: python, csv

I have multiple CSV files which I need to parse in a loop to gather information.
The problem is that while they are the same format, some are delimited by '\t' and others by ','.
After this, I want to remove the double-quote from around the string.

Can python split via multiple possible delimiters?

At the minute, I can split the line with one by using:

```
f = open(filename, "r")
fields = f.readlines()
for fs in fields:
    sf = fs.split('\t')
    tf = [fi.strip ('"') for fi in sf]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python regex split a string by one of two delimiters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618551/python-regex-split-a-string-by-one-of-two-delimiters)

Comment: Please don't close this as duplicate: As I say in my answer, splitting manually is the wrong solution here, so the other question will not be helpful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Splitting the file like that is not a good idea: It will fail if there is a comma within one of the fields. For example (for a tab-delimited file): The line `"field1"\t"Hello, world"\t"field3"` will be split into 4 fields instead of 3.

Instead, you should use the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module. It contains the helpful [`Sniffer`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer) class which can detect which delimiters are used in the file. The csv module will also remove the double-quotes for you.

```
import csv

csvfile = open("example.csv")
dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024))
csvfile.seek(0)
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect)

for line in reader:
    #process line
```

Comment: +1 In python you usually find some tools that can help you with your problem as long as you are working with some familiar format. A lesson learned from many aborted attempts of reinventing the wheel :)

Comment: What does 1024 refer to?

Comment: @user809695 It means to determine the format based on the first 1024 bytes of the file. It can be any other number, it just needs to be big enough to contain enough data to determine the format.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with regex (optionally compiled):

```
sf = re.split(r'[,\t]', fs)
```

This doesn't account for e.g. commas inside tab-delimited fields.  I would see if the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module is helpful.