# Index Error when using python to read BLAST output in csv format

Tags: python, list, csv, blast

Apologies for the long question, I have been trying to solve this bug but I cant work out what Im doing wrong! I have included an example of the data so you can see what Im working with.

I have data output from a BLAST search as below:

```
    # BLASTN 2.2.29+                                            
# Query: Cryptocephalus androgyne                                           
# Database: SANfive                                         
# Fields: query id   subject id  % identity  alignment length    mismatches  gap opens   q. start    q. end  s. start    s. end  evalue  bit score
# 7 hits found                                          
Cryptocephalus  M00964:19:000000000-A4YV1:1:2110:23842:21326    99.6    250 1   0   125 374 250 1   1.00E-128   457
Cryptocephalus  M00964:19:000000000-A4YV1:1:1112:19704:18005    85.37   246 36  0   90  335 246 1   4.00E-68    255
Cryptocephalus  M00964:19:000000000-A4YV1:1:2106:14369:15227    77.42   248 50  3   200 444 245 1   3.00E-34    143
Cryptocephalus  M00964:19:000000000-A4YV1:1:2102:5533:11928 78.1    137 30  0   3   139 114 250 2.00E-17    87.9
Cryptocephalus  M00964:19:000000000-A4YV1:1:1110:28729:12868    81.55   103 19  0   38  140 104 2   6.00E-17    86.1
Cryptocephalus  M00964:19:000000000-A4YV1:1:1113:11427:16440    78.74   127 27  0   3   129 124 250 6.00E-17    86.1
Cryptocephalus  M00964:19:000000000-A4YV1:1:2110:12170:20594    78.26   115 25  0   3   117 102 216 1.00E-13    75
# BLASTN 2.2.29+                                            
# Query: Cryptocephalus aureolus                                            
# Database: SANfive                                         
# Fields: query id   subject id  % identity  alignment length    mismatches  gap opens   q. start    q. end  s. start    s. end  evalue  bit score
# 10 hits found                                         
Cryptocephalus  M00964:19:000000000-A4YV1:1:2111:20990:19930    97.2    250 7   0   119 368 250 1   1.00E-118   424
Cryptocephalus  M00964:19:000000000-A4YV1:1:1105:20676:23942    86.89   206 27  0   5   210 209 4   7.00E-61    231
Cryptocephalus  M00964:19:000000000-A4YV1:1:1113:6534:23125 97.74   133 3   0   1   133 133 1   3.00E-60    230
Cryptocephalus  M00964:21:000000000-A4WJV:1:2104:11955:19015    89.58   144 15  0   512 655 1   144 2.00E-46    183
Cryptocephalus  M00964:21:000000000-A4WJV:1:1109:14814:10240    88.28   128 15  0   83  210 11  138 2.00E-37    154
Cryptocephalus  M00964:21:000000000-A4WJV:1:1105:4530:13833 79.81   208 42  0   3   210 211 4   6.00E-37    152
Cryptocephalus  M00964:19:000000000-A4YV1:1:2108:13133:14967    98.7    77  1   0   1   77  77  1   2.00E-32    137
Cryptocephalus  M00964:19:000000000-A4YV1:1:1109:14328:3682 100 60  0   0   596 655 251 192 1.00E-24    111
Cryptocephalus  M00964:19:000000000-A4YV1:1:1105:19070:25181    100 53  0   0   1   53  53  1   8.00E-21    99
Cryptocephalus  M00964:19:000000000-A4YV1:1:1109:20848:27419    100 28  0   0   1   28  28  1   6.00E-07    52.8
# BLASTN 2.2.29+                                            
# Query: Cryptocephalus cynarae                                         
# Database: SANfive                                         
# Fields: query id   subject id  % identity  alignment length    mismatches  gap opens   q. start    q. end  s. start    s. end  evalue  bit score
# 2 hits found                                          
Cryptocephalus  M00964:21:000000000-A4WJV:1:2107:12228:15885    90.86   175 16  0   418 592 4   178 5.00E-62    235
Cryptocephalus  M00964:21:000000000-A4WJV:1:1110:20463:5044 84.52   168 26  0   110 277 191 24  2.00E-41    167
```

and I have saved this as a csv, again shown below

```
# BLASTN 2.2.29+,,,,,,,,,,,
# Query: Cryptocephalus androgyne,,,,,,,,,,,
# Database: SANfive,,,,,,,,,,,
# Fields: query id, subject id, % identity, alignment length, mismatches, gap opens, q. start, q. end, s. start, s. end, evalue, bit score
# 7 hits found,,,,,,,,,,,
Cryptocephalus,M00964:19:000000000-A4YV1:1:2110:23842:21326,99.6,250,1,0,125,374,250,1,1.00E-128,457
Cryptocephalus,M00964:19:000000000-A4YV1:1:1112:19704:18005,85.37,246,36,0,90,335,246,1,4.00E-68,255
Cryptocephalus,M00964:19:000000000-A4YV1:1:2106:14369:15227,77.42,248,50,3,200,444,245,1,3.00E-34,143
Cryptocephalus,M00964:19:000000000-A4YV1:1:2102:5533:11928,78.1,137,30,0,3,139,114,250,2.00E-17,87.9
Cryptocephalus,M00964:19:000000000-A4YV1:1:1110:28729:12868,81.55,103,19,0,38,140,104,2,6.00E-17,86.1
Cryptocephalus,M00964:19:000000000-A4YV1:1:1113:11427:16440,78.74,127,27,0,3,129,124,250,6.00E-17,86.1
Cryptocephalus,M00964:19:000000000-A4YV1:1:2110:12170:20594,78.26,115,25,0,3,117,102,216,1.00E-13,75
# BLASTN 2.2.29+,,,,,,,,,,,
# Query: Cryptocephalus aureolus,,,,,,,,,,,
# Database: SANfive,,,,,,,,,,,
# Fields: query id, subject id, % identity, alignment length, mismatches, gap opens, q. start, q. end, s. start, s. end, evalue, bit score
# 10 hits found,,,,,,,,,,,
Cryptocephalus,M00964:19:000000000-A4YV1:1:2111:20990:19930,97.2,250,7,0,119,368,250,1,1.00E-118,424
Cryptocephalus,M00964:19:000000000-A4YV1:1:1105:20676:23942,86.89,206,27,0,5,210,209,4,7.00E-61,231
Cryptocephalus,M00964:19:000000000-A4YV1:1:1113:6534:23125,97.74,133,3,0,1,133,133,1,3.00E-60,230
Cryptocephalus,M00964:21:000000000-A4WJV:1:2104:11955:19015,89.58,144,15,0,512,655,1,144,2.00E-46,183
Cryptocephalus,M00964:21:000000000-A4WJV:1:1109:14814:10240,88.28,128,15,0,83,210,11,138,2.00E-37,154
Cryptocephalus,M00964:21:000000000-A4WJV:1:1105:4530:13833,79.81,208,42,0,3,210,211,4,6.00E-37,152
Cryptocephalus,M00964:19:000000000-A4YV1:1:2108:13133:14967,98.7,77,1,0,1,77,77,1,2.00E-32,137
Cryptocephalus,M00964:19:000000000-A4YV1:1:1109:14328:3682,100,60,0,0,596,655,251,192,1.00E-24,111
Cryptocephalus,M00964:19:000000000-A4YV1:1:1105:19070:25181,100,53,0,0,1,53,53,1,8.00E-21,99
Cryptocephalus,M00964:19:000000000-A4YV1:1:1109:20848:27419,100,28,0,0,1,28,28,1,6.00E-07,52.8
```

I have designed a short script that goes through the percentage identity and if it is above a threshold finds the queryID and adds it to a list before removing duplicates from the list.

```
import csv
from pylab import plot,show

#Making a function to see if a string is a number or not
def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

#Importing the CSV file, using sniffer to check the delimiters used 
#In the first 1024 bytes

ImportFile = raw_input("What is the name of your import file? ")
csvfile = open(ImportFile, "rU")
dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024))
csvfile.seek(0)
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect)

#Finding species over 98%

Species98 = []
Species95to97 = []
Species90to94 = []
Species85to89 = []
Species80to84 = []
Species75to79 = []
SpeciesBelow74 = []



for line in reader:
    if is_number(line[2])== True:
        if float(line[2])>=98:
            Species98.append(line[0])
        elif 97>=float(line[2])>=95:
            Species95to97.append(line[0])
        elif 94>=float(line[2])>=90:
            Species90to94.append(line[0])
        elif 89>=float(line[2])>=85:
            Species85to89.append(line[0])
        elif 84>=float(line[2])>=80:
            Species80to84.append(line[0])
        elif 79>=float(line[2])>=75:
            Species75to79.append(line[0])
        elif float(line[2])<=74:
            SpeciesBelow74.append(line[0])

def f7(seq):
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    return [ x for x in seq if x not in seen and not seen_add(x)]


Species98=f7(Species98)
print len(Species98), "species over 98"

Species95to97=f7(Species95to97) #removing duplicates
search_set = set().union(Species98)
Species95to97 = [x for x in Species95to97 if x not in search_set]
print len(Species95to97), "species between 95-97"

Species90to94=f7(Species90to94)
search_set = set().union(Species98, Species95to97)
Species90to94 = [x for x in Species90to94 if x not in search_set]
print len(Species90to94), "species between 90-94"

Species85to89=f7(Species85to89)
search_set = set().union(Species98, Species95to97, Species90to94)
Species85to89 = [x for x in Species85to89 if x not in search_set]               
print len(Species85to89), "species between 85-89"

Species80to84=f7(Species80to84)
search_set = set().union(Species98, Species95to97, Species90to94, Species85to89)
Species80to84 = [x for x in Species80to84 if x not in search_set]               
print len(Species80to84), "species between 80-84"

Species75to79=f7(Species75to79)
search_set = set().union(Species98, Species95to97, Species90to94, Species85to89,Species80to84)
Species75to79 = [x for x in Species75to79 if x not in search_set]       
print len(Species75to79), "species between 75-79"

SpeciesBelow74=f7(SpeciesBelow74)
search_set = set().union(Species98, Species95to97, Species90to94, Species85to89,Species80to84, Species75to79)
SpeciesBelow74 = [x for x in SpeciesBelow74 if x not in search_set] 
print len(SpeciesBelow74), "species below 74"

#Finding species 95-97%
```

The script works perfectly most of the time but every so often I get the error shown below

```
File "FindingSpeciesRepresentation.py", line 35, in <module>
    if is_number(line[2])== "True":
IndexError: list index out of range
```

But if I change the script so it prints `line[2]` it prints all the identities as I would expect. Do you have any idea what could be going wrong? Again apologies for the wall of data.

This has been partly taken from my earlier question: [Extracting BLAST output columns in CSV form with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23404971/extracting-blast-output-columns-in-csv-form-with-python)

Comment: a) I cannot reproduce your problem on the text and code you provide. b) For problems like these you're much more likely to get an answer with a short, self-contained reproducible example. (For example, you should have just shown the code that read the file, not all the lines before and after meant to process it, after checking that that short version contained the problem) c) Are you by any chance writing to this file (with a different program) at the same time as you are running this file? This would mean the final line may be truncated sometimes, which would be your "every so often" problem.

Comment: d) If you had a line like: `if l.startswith("#"): continue` that skipped comments, you wouldn't have to add all those commas in the comment lines

Comment: Sorry, I havent asked a debugging problem before and assumed more was better! I'm not writing to the file and I still get the error even if I cut down the code to reading in the csv file and printing line[2].

Comment: In that case I do not think you're running it on the CSV file you provide. Are you telling it the wrong file at the prompt (for example, the non-CSV version you show at the top of your question?)

Comment: As far as Im aware I am, I will remove the other file from the directory to check. I make the non-CSV version into the CSV by importing into excel and telling it to delimit by tab and commas, when I look at the excel document everything is where it should be so I save it as a csv. I just redid this process and got a new error that I havent seen before: _csv.Error: line contains NULL byte. I have no idea what Im doing wrong but it may be the way im making it into a csv. THanks for your help so far.

Comment: Can you try to make a super-minimal version of this problem? That is, see if you can cut out everything but 4-5 lines of code and a few lines of your CSV file and still consistently get the error. (Hardcoding the location of your CSV file, or at least providing it as a command line argument, would help since it avoids any chance it was entered incorrectly). In the process there's a good chance you will end up figuring out your problem anyway. But if you don't, post the new input file and code and you'll be more likely to get a helpful answer

Comment: Haha I solved it straight away! The last line of my code says "#BLAST processed 42 queries", or something to that extent and therefore isnt properly delimitated on the final line. Thank you though because it would have taken me longer to figure out without your advice

Comment: sounds right to me! glad to hear it's fixed